# How to install Pandoc for Windows?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have been to their website.  I have viewed a YouTube on a related subject.  And, so far I don't really get it.  My objective is to use Pandoc in conjunction with R Markdown to convert R Markdown HTML document into either Word or Pdf files.

Answer (score 6):

You can install `pandoc` in several ways:

1. Using the x86 or x64 executable from here and installng like any other Windows app: [pandoc downloads](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.2.1)
2. Using the x86 or x64 flavor of the `zip` file (same link shown above), and unpack it on the folder of your preference. Then, set manually the path to that folder. Pandoc is only a couple of files `pandoc.exe` and `pandoc-citeproc.exe`. You may even copy then to your `/bin` folder of your preference if want to save adding another PATH.
3. Using the R package `installr`, and then run `installr::install.pandoc()`.
   It will automatically install the Windows `msi` and add the PATH for you. 
   You may review the user path in environment variables: `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Pandoc\`.

Reload the environment variables by restarting your PC.

Comment: Are you sure option 3 is correct? I tried to install Pandoc this way under R 4.0.3 on Windows 10. It appeared to work. But, I wanted Pandoc because R's package manager uses it for creating documentation. I was following Hadley Wickham's book on packaging, https://r-pkgs.org/man.html , and trying to build my vignettes by calling devtools::build_vignettes() . When I did this, R gave me the message "Pandoc (>= 1.12.3) and/or pandoc-citeproc not available".

Comment: @Phil  I will have to check. I wrote this in 2018. With so many updates in the packages I am not sure if it applies today. I will revert to you soon.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the [Chocolatey package manager](https://chocolatey.org) installed on your  Windows machine, you can install the [Pandoc package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/pandoc) with:

```
choco install pandoc
```

Comment: if you get permission errors when trying to install -  first open PowerShell terminal as administrator - and then run the above command.

Answer (score 2):

If you have RStudio installed (and most R users do) then you already have a pandoc binary.  Maybe just add that directory to your `$PATH` ?

Comment: Can you flesh out a bit how you would actually install Pandoc.  I am not a professional R coder by any means.  But, I can learn and get by ok.

Comment: Same as everything else:  From *source* you install the (required and rather involved) Haskell build environment.  Else from *binary* from the Pandoc site.  Or else you use somebody else's build -- which is what I suggested here as RStudio ships one.  Pandoc is orthogonal to R: It is just yet another tool that can also be used by R.